# How to modify a string value without pass char ** as parameter?

Tags: c, string

Some C functions can modify the string value without that I pass the address of it.
For example:

```
char * s = "foo\0";
tobaa(s); /* Now foo is modified to something like "baa" */
printf("%s", s); /* baa */
```

How do I this?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly put `\0` at the end of a string literal. It is automatically done. And change `char *s` to `char s[]`

Comment: @Shahbaz: Thanks for your notice. It's C standard? and all C compilers do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
void tobaa(char *s)
{
    strcpy(s, "baa");
}
```

Also, the extra `\0` character is unnecessary, it is added automatically.
Also, make sure you pass a mutable buffer to `tobaa` or you invoke UB.

Comment: What if I have to allocate memory to s inside the function?
e.g.  
`string str = createFileName(fileNumber);
s = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (str.length()+1));
strcpy(s, str.c_str());`

While in main `char* s = NULL;`

Answer (score 4):

First thing to mention is that your code involves **undefined behaviour**; you are not allowed to modify string literals.

But to answer your question, a `char *` already **is** a pointer.  Specifically, it's a pointer to an array of characters.  So if you pass this pointer to a function, that function can modify the underlying characters.